# Rendered result is dark

Tags: rendering, mesh, image, lighting

I've applied the picture in the base color as the BDSF but the rendered plane seems a lot darker than the actual reference image (on the left side).  I'm using and HDRI and added a light. Any ideas how I can get the plane (on the right hand side) to be as bright? Appreciate the help[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Plug Image texture directly to Material Output if you dont mind that board would not be affected by lights ... btw if you use Eevee engine - HDRi does not participate in lightning at all (you would have to add Irradiance object) or use Cycles. Or your issue is just Spelucal value that make material reflect envi :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe replace the principled BSDF to emission shader [image: a]
and you can increase the strength of the emission